# Linq Filtering items with ForEach crashes for large data set

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I want to filter `Recon` items from a list. I want to take all the `Recon` objects that has a `Transaction` object with the property `SrcObjType` equal to "13" in its `Transactions` List.

```
// The model is like this 

public partial class Recon
{

  public int ReconNum { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public partial class Transaction
{
  public long TransactionId { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> DocumentDate { get; set; }
  public string SrcObjTyp { get; set; }
  public virtual Recon Recon { get; set; }
}

// this works for a few items but crashes on large data sets (million rows large)

List<Recon> reconsWithType13Trans = new List<Recon>();
db.Transactions.Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
  .ToList().ForEach(t => reconsWithType13Trans.Add(t.Recon));
```

I think the foreach is eating to much memory and then the program would raise an Out of Memory Exception.

My question is how can I do to filter these items as efficiently as possible. If possible without requiring much memory. Is there another possibility without using foreach to achieve this kind of filtering ?

Comment: Crash? What is the exception? `program would` is not helping. Is it throwing `OutofMemoryException`

Comment: Out of memory like I said.

Comment: Try this: `List<Recon> reconsWithType13Trans = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13").Select(t => t.Recon).ToList();`

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM How that's going to help?

Comment: What actual purpose does loading millions of items into memory serve? How will your users see this data?

Comment: @Simon It is for faster processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Recon> reconsWithType13Trans = db.Transactions
                     .Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
                     .Select(t => t.Recon).ToList();
```

This wouldn't load all the `Transaction`s in the memory, only their `Recon`.

You can also use an `IQueryable<Recon>` and take advantage of the deferred execution in EF:

```
var reconsWithType13Trans = db.Transactions
                     .Where(t => t.SrcObjTyp == "13")
                     .Select(t => t.Recon);
```

Comment: Check your code. `ToList()`, as the name suggests, returns a list.